# Creating Folder issue c# windows

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a folder in c#. my program has permissions and its running as admin still it throws exception not sure what to do...

this is the code

```
        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\CON");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }


  Exception message is Could not find a part of the path 'C:\'.
```

Comment: Does it work when you change the name of the directory? I remember that `CON` was a special device in dos to represent the console. It might have something to do with that...

Comment: that is reserved name